# How to use FOR XML Path in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

Can you please help me will FOR XML PATH works in Azure Synapse.
If not what will be the alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case you you're looking to use FOR XML to prepare e.g. column names for a dynamic pivot query, then the string_agg function is what you are looking for.

[string_agg documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pools (and serverless SQL pools) do **not** support the `FOR XML` syntax as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15):

[image: FOR XML not supported in Synapse]

The easiest thing to do would be use Azure SQL DB to do your XML processing, eg use a pipeline to land your data there, call a Stored Proc activity to do the processing then retrieve it.  Another fun alternative would be to use a Synapse notebook and use Python or Scala to process the XML.

Comment: i dont have Azure SQL instance. is there any alternative for XML path ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results please?